# In Dredd (2012), what was Kay thinking about, that freaked Anderson out so much?

Tags: movie, dredd

In Dredd (the 2012 reboot film), at one point Kay is trying to freak out Anderson by having her read his mind psychically while he thinks of outrageous things.

The violent sex thought doesn't seem to faze her much, but then he thinks of something that really "freaks her out," although we never see it.

Is it stated anywhere what he was thinking in this scene, either in production notes or deleted scenes or anything like that?

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing in the [script](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8kCGU0ORru0C&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=ANDERSON%20turns%20and%20gazes%20at%20him%20evenly&source=bl&ots=PNeheSpcLK&sig=_iG4tbfwyybieI-NgwEo4TH5H7I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EUSdVJraCMj9UMuSgJgL&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ANDERSON%20turns%20and%20gazes%20at%20him%20evenly&f=false), earlier leaked script or visual script other than what you see in the film;

> **KAY** (CONT'D) *Kind of hard to believe it's real. Like - what am I thinking about right now?*
>
> ANDERSON turns and gazes at him evenly, determined to show he can't
>   get to her.
>
> **ANDERSON  :** *You're picturing a violent sexual liason between the two of us in an pointless attempt to shock me.*
>
> KAY raises his eyebrows.
>
> **KAY :** *You're good.*   (beat)
>   *But I wasn't trying to shock you. If I'd been trying to shock you, I'd have thought of this.*
>
> ANDERSON suddenly winces at the image he had dropped on her.   Then -
>   snaps. She lashes out with her fist. Catches KAY full in the face, and
>   drops him.
>
> **ANDERSON :** *What are you thinking about now?*
>
> Through bloody and busted lips, KAY looks up at her and smiles. He
>   might be bleeding and cuffed, but the victory in this encounter is
>   his.

but based on their next encounter, it's reasonable to assume that he was picturing her performing *consensual* oral sex on him. As to why she found this so disturbing, you need to understand that Anderson's father was sexually abusive to her. She's not especially agitated by the idea of a violent assault, but she's instantly shaken by the implied loss of control.

[image]
<sub><sup>**Judge Anderson : Engram**</sup></sub>